# Getting a Monthly Date Range

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How can you make a date range in a big query? A date range starts from 29th of the month and ends with 28th of the next month. It should be like this

Date         |   Starting Date     |     Ending Date

03-13-2020    |   02-29-2020        |    03-28-2021

06-30-2020     |  06-29-2020        |    07-28-2021

01-01-2021    |   12-29-2020        |   01-28-2021

11-11-2021    |   10-28-2021          |  11-29-2021

Actually, i make an article on it.
Check this out:

https://www.theaccountingtactics.com/2021/12/BigQueryBQ-DateProblems-DateSituations-that-are-Hard-to-Analyze-and-Takes-Time-ToCrack%20.html?m=1

Comment: What happens for most dates in March, when there is not usually a February 29 to start on?

Comment: Also, it is preferable to remove the link to your article and paste the table into your question.

Comment: I already edit the question. I dont know how to create a table.

Comment: If it is leap year, it will directed to March 1 , 2021

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
create temp function set_day(date date, day int64) as (
  ifnull(
    safe.date(extract(year from date), extract(month from date), day), 
    last_day(date)
  )
);
select Date, 
  set_day(Starting_Date, 29) as Starting_Date,
  set_day(Ending_Date, 28) as Ending_Date
from (
  select *, if(extract(day from Date) < 29, 
      struct(date_sub(Date, interval 1 month) as Starting_Date, Date as Ending_Date),
      struct(Date as Starting_Date, date_add(Date, interval 1 month) as Ending_Date)
    ).*
  from your_table 
)
```

if applied to sample data as in your question

```
with your_table as (
  select date '2020-03-13' Date union all
  select '2021-03-13' union all
  select '2020-06-30' union all
  select '2021-01-01' union all
  select '2021-11-11' 
)
```

output is

[image]

You can test whole stuff using below

```
create temp function set_day(date date, day int64) as (
  ifnull(
    safe.date(extract(year from date), extract(month from date), day), 
    last_day(date)
  )
);
with your_table as (
  select date '2020-03-13' Date union all
  select '2021-03-13' union all
  select '2020-06-30' union all
  select '2021-01-01' union all
  select '2021-11-11' 
) 
select Date, 
  set_day(Starting_Date, 29) as Starting_Date,
  set_day(Ending_Date, 28) as Ending_Date
from (
  select *, if(extract(day from Date) < 29, 
      struct(date_sub(Date, interval 1 month) as Starting_Date, Date as Ending_Date),
      struct(Date as Starting_Date, date_add(Date, interval 1 month) as Ending_Date)
    ).*
  from your_table 
)
```

Comment: I tried to copy and paste your query on the Google Cloud Platform. It's an error.
I am not familiar with some of your functions. Apology for that..  I'm just a beginner in Big Query.

Comment: I added whole test code - try again and let me know if still problem(s)

Comment: Wow. It is now working but I do not know the usage of some functions. 
I also made a query to get it but it is longer than yours. 

Link: https://www.theaccountingtactics.com/2022/01/big-query-sql-date-problems-solution.html

Anyways, Thank you..